# to infinitive interpretation: successiveness vs. purpose

Tags: infinitives

She waited until Ellie went off to the bog; then got up, **came over to tell me** she was leaving, and said I could have my bangle back; the one I gave her when we had our commitment ceremony. She chucked it down on the table in front of me, with everyone fucking gawping. So I picked it up and said, ‘Anyone fancy this, it’s going spare?’ and she fucked off.” (The Cuckoo’s Calling, Robert Galbraith)

I would incline to read the bold part as: “*came over and told me*.” But I wonder if it can have this meaning: “*came over in order to tell me*.”? In many cases, when there isn't obvious cause-effect relationship with the previous verb, it seems that to read to-infinitive as the former way - successively or resultatively - is more natural than purpose interpretation. 
Which way do I have to read the example? And is there some tips to distinguish between the two interpretations?

Comment: Yes, *in order to tell me* is the correct interpretation.

Comment: "to" there means "having the intention".  `I phoned him to say that I was going to be late.`  Verb X intending to do Verb Y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> came over to tell me

Right, that means "came over in order to tell me". It is actually not cause-effect, it's rather a purpose and a mean to achieve it.

> came over and told me

Could you provide a clear example in which this kind of interpretation is obviously correct?